# function pointer to a templated class method

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to achieve the following code pattern.

```
struct Worker {
    void update(/* function pointer */) {

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            /* function execution */
        }
    }
}

template <typename t_derive>
struct BaseCrtp {
    void method1() {
        static_cast<t_derive*>(this)->method1();
    }

    void method2() {
        static_cast<t_derive*>(this)->worker.update(/*fptr of Derived1::method2*/);
    }
}

struct Derived1 : public BaseCrtp<Derived1> {
    Worker worker;

    void method1() {
        std::cout << "Derived1::method1" << std::endl;
    }

    void method2() {
        std::cout << "Derived1::method2" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I would like to call Derived1's method2 in the instance of Worker::update. How can I define a function pointer that I can inject into the update function.

Comment: It looks like `update` doesn't want a pointer to member but a plain function pointer. Consider using `std::function` instead.

Comment: Because `method2` is not a static member function, you can only call it if you have an object of type `Derived1` to call it on.  `worker` doesn't have such an argument.  As molbdnilo says: You need std::function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Worker {
    void update(/* function pointer */) {
     .....
```

---

Make `Worker::update` a *template member-function*:

```
struct Worker {
    template<typename Func>
    void update(Func&& func) {
     .....
```

or use `std::function`:

```
struct Worker {
    void update(std::function<void()> func) {
     .....
```

---

Then pass the callback via a lambda in your `BaseCrtp<>::method2` as below:

```
void method2() {
    static_cast<t_derive*>(this)->worker.update(
        [this]{ static_cast<t_derive*>(this)->method2(); }
    );
}
```

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Worker {

    template<typename Func>
    void update(Func&& func) {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            func();
        }
    }

    //alternatively....
    //
    //void update(std::function<void()> func) {
    //    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //        func();
    //    }
    //}
};

template <typename t_derive>
struct BaseCrtp {
    void method1() {
        static_cast<t_derive*>(this)->method1();
    }

    void method2() {
        static_cast<t_derive*>(this)->worker.update(
            [this]{ static_cast<t_derive*>(this)->method2(); }
        );
    }
};

struct Derived1 : public BaseCrtp<Derived1> {
    Worker worker;

    void method1() {
        std::cout << "Derived1::method1" << std::endl;
    }

    void method2() {
        std::cout << "Derived1::method2" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void process(BaseCrtp<T>& t){
    t.method2();
}

int main(){
    Derived1 d1;
    process(d1);
}
```

As seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d31218b6ad8a787) or [here (`std::function` alternative)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb0afbe86af9258c).

---

Answer (score 1):

As Martin Bonner suggested I think you could make use of Worker template with type template parameter containing Derived class and non-type template parameter with a pointer to the method you would like to invoke. This can be done as follows:

```
template <class T, void (T::*)(void)>
struct Worker {
    void update(T *t) {
        t->method2();
    }
};

struct Foo {
  void method2() { }
  Worker<Foo, &Foo::method2> worker;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.worker.update(&foo);
}
```

[[online demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/COIY09CChcJGbT7t)

This when using compiler optimization should most probably be inlined now which is actually the point of using crtp in a first place:

[[godbolt]](https://godbolt.org/g/wb5VVG)